# MathQuill can't work well on iphone,but it's well on simulators

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mathquill

I'm trying to use the MathQuill to render a mathematical formula with UIWebView and I'm using the following the method:

```
(void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(nullable NSURL *)baseURL;
```

I have coped the `mathQuill.css` and `mathQuill.js` to the bundle and when I run the app on simulator, the mathematical formula is rendered by right way, but when I run the app on  my iPhone 6+, the mathematical formula doesn't work correctly.

Can anyone give me some advice ?

--------update-----

I have found the solution.That's just because the jQuery CDN of google can't visited  in China without VPN. And when I run the app on simulator,the VPN works on my iMac,but my iPhone not work with VPN when connecting WiFi!